# How to use ip address as url in config file in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

When I use ip address with port number as url value in my config file I am getting the following error

```
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported
```

But this is working fine when I use a website like "http://www.google.com"
What I have to use to make this ip url format supported...

PFB is the config file I tried on

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="baseURL" value="http://255.255.255.1:6060"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Show the code that actually reads the `baseURL` and uses it

Comment: without http:// also giving the same error..

Comment: public static string BaseUrl
        { get
            {return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseURL"];
            }
        }

Comment: When I use ; it gives an error saying hexadecimal value 0x3b is illegal.

Comment: i edited this, for some reason it placed it in when i pasted. do not use that

Comment: Tag needs to be closed <add key="baseURL" value="255.255.255.1:6060"/>

Comment: Yeah, I closed it, but still the same error happening

Comment: is your ip address valid, and is the port set properly by the server.

Comment: I don't have any problems to read ip address. I think the exception has raised in another place, when You use for example classes from System.IO namespace.

Comment: my url ip and port are valid, they are working fine when I load it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("UrlNode");
```

with

```
<add key="UrlNode" value="http://node.brainlap.dev" />
```

And it has always been working.

I'm using .Net Version 4.5.

Comment: try using an ip address with port number like 255.255.255.1:6060

Comment: Since it's a configuration file that's likely different in my local environment, I have already used ips and ports etc, also without any problems. In the end, this value is just a string. Your error most likely happens when you try to convert it. That's why it'd be useful if you add a snipped from the code where you actually use this setting value.

Comment: public static string BaseUrl
        { get
            { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseURL"];
            }
        }

Comment: I am not doing any conversion here

Comment: if (driver == null)
{  startTime = DateTime.Now;
   string fileTime = string.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy} {1}\\", startTime, BaseUrl.Replace("https://", "").Replace("http://", "").Replace("www", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("com", "").ToUpper());
 newFolder = "\\\\192.168.2.234\\I\\Result\\" + fileTime;
 results = folder + string.Format("BuildResults_{0:MM-dd-yy h-mm-ss}.html", DateTime.Now);
NameDownloadFolder();
stringResults.Add("");
if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
{DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)}
DirectoryInfo dirp = Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadFolder);

Comment: In the above code I am getting "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The given path's format is not supported." in the debug mode on "DirectoryInfo dirp = directory.CreateDirectory(folder)"

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem.
I didnt replace the ":" in the fileTime string. In order to do that I have to add another replace, Replace(":", "").

This is working well now.
Thanks a lot for your help friends.